# In Parse Local Datastore, how can I perform a query for any pin name?

Tags: parse-platform, pinning, local-datastore

Whenever you pin an object, the object is always either implicitly or explicitly (`[object pin*]` vs. `[object pin*WithName:@"pin name"]`, where * is an optional `InBackground`) associated with a pin name — either `PFObjectPinName` by default or a pin name that's supplied by the user.

When querying, similarly you implicitly or explicitly supply a pin name to query from. However, I would like to know of all the objects that are locally stored, without necessarily knowing all the pin names on the system.

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think to query for ANY pin, simply use `fromLocalDatastore`. Its comments say:

```
/*!
 @abstract Change the source of this query to all pinned objects.

 @warning Requires Local Datastore to be enabled.

 @returns The same instance of `PFQuery` as the receiver. This allows method chaining.

 @see cachePolicy
 */
- (instancetype)fromLocalDatastore;
```